# Setting targetPipelineVersion dynamically for pipeline github source webhook with CDK

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm trying to setup a github source webhook using the CfnWebhook class.

However, the builder only allows a Number on the targetPipelineVersion field and pipeline.getPipelineVersion() returns a string.

I need this to be sourced dynamically from the Pipeline object.

```java
CfnWebhook.Builder.create(this, "githubWebhook")
                //other properties...
                .targetPipelineVersion(pipeline.getPipelineVersion())
                .build();
```

Are there any alternatives to go around this?